# How do I get my model.fit_generator() method to show the number of data points instead of number of batches while training the model?

Tags: keras, computer-vision, deep-linking

I am training a model using keras and below is my fit_generator call. Could someone please help me to set the progress bar to show the number of data points instead of batches(steps)?

```
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, epochs=1, verbose=2, 
                     validation_data=val_generator, 
                     validation_steps=validation_steps, class_weight=None, workers=1, initial_epoch=0,callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

I have tried with different values of verbose but it didn't help.

Appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: What does it mean "data points"?

Comment: let's say, I have 10,000 images(data points) and when the training through epochs is happening(1/15,2/15), I get the progress of steps(batches) like 25/34,26/34. Instead, what I want is, the progress of how many images are being processed something like, 2222/10000, 3000/10000. Is there a way to do it.